# How to debug requests in spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got an app in spring, which uses spring rest and spring mvc. I've got a controller which on POST adds a comment. Method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Comment> addComment(Comment comment) {
    return service.addComment(comment);
}
```

I'm sending a request of type "application/json" with data set to {author:"text", "text":"commentText"}, and when I'm debugging inside of that method, I get null values on both properties.
This is my Comment model:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String author;
    private String text;

    public Comment() {

    }

    public Comment(String author, String text) {
        this.author = author;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Comment{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I debug, what went wrong ? With classic servlet, I would get a request and I would create a Comment object by myself using some json library like jackson or gson, but here I'm a bit blocked, because everything is done using annotations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to annotate the method parameter with `@RequestBody` to tell Spring where to populate it from.

Comment: That has fixed my problem, thank you, but still it would be nice to get information what is fired before the method annotated with request mapping.

Comment: @MaKro Turn up logging on `org.springframework.web.DispatcherServlet` to `DEBUG` level.